# Node.JS: Best way to handle max requests per minute to a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, limit

I'm sorry if this question as already been answered and I hope I'm not breaking any SO rule, if so, in advance I apologise... 
I was wondering what was the best way to handle a request limiter? I've seen a bunch of throttles and rate-limiters online but I'm not sure how or if it could apply in my case.

I'm doing a bunch of [OUTGOING] request-promises based on an Array and on a server I can only make 90 request per minute. My request-promises are generated by this command: `return Promise.all(array.map(request))`.

I was thinking to handle it like this:

```
var i = 0;

return rp({
        url: uri,
        json: true,
      }).then((data) => {
        if (i <=90) {
          i ++;
          return data;
        } else {
          return i;
        }
      });
```

but I'm not sure if it will be a really effective way to handle it plus, I'm not sure how to handle the time relation yet... :S

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry I'm still a huge beginner...

Comment: Are you trying to throttle the amount of outgoing requests, or incoming requests?

Comment: Hey Matt! Outgoing. The server will only accept 90 request per minute basically.

Comment: It's probably impossible to throttle requests on the client side, given that if you hit 90 requests, the user can just refresh the page and send the requests again.

Comment: With that being said, what you have seems to be a solution (assuming that the user is not constantly refreshing the page), but you should add a 60 second timer that will reset the count back to zero. Otherwise you will only be able to send 90 requests, regardless of the amount of time passed.

Comment: OK. But in this case I'm the only client. The objective is to limit my app that would run alone (won't be used externally by anybody else).

Comment: Great! Thanks @Matthew! Any ideas on where I could find material on the timer?

Comment: Take a look at [this `limiter` example](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter#usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requests are started from different code parts, it might be useful to implement sth like a *server queue* which awaits the request until it is allowed to do so. The general handler:

```
var fromUrl = new Map();

function Server(url, maxPerMinute){
 if(fromUrl.has(url)) return fromUrl.get(url);
 fromUrl.set(url,this);

  this.tld = url;
  this.maxPerMinute = maxPerMinute;
  this.queue = [];
  this.running = false;

}


  Server.prototype ={
   run(d){
    if(this.running && !d) return;
    var curr = this.queue.shift();
    if(!curr){
      this.running = false;
      return;
    }
   var [url,resolve] = curr;
   Promise.all([
     request(this.tld + url),
     new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000*60/this.maxPerMinute)
    ]).then(([res]) => {
       resolve(res);
       this.run(true);
    });
  },
  request(url){
   return new Promise(res => {
      this.queue.push([url,res]);
      this.run();
    });
  }
};

module.exports = Server;
```

Usable like this:

```
 var google = new require("server")("http://google.com");

google.maxPerMinute = 90;

google.request("/api/v3/hidden/service").then(res => ...);
```

Comment: Hey Jonas! Thanks again and a million for the continued follow-up. It has been pretty difficult for me to get into my project over the past few days. I must admit that your answer would exactly be what I'm looking for but I'm afraid that it's too complicated for me at the moment... Or to put it another way, I don't have the slightest idea on how to implement your code within mine. I need to get into every single portion of it to understand it correctly and it's going to take me a while... If you had a little more literature on this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @ardzii well the only thing i could recommend would be the MDN docs, the upper code is completely self thought, so it doesnt use any common patterns.

Comment: Hehehe! That's exactly where I'm at right now... Still, there are so many things of that code I don't know that's very confusing! But I'll get it eventually! I'll may come back here for some clarifications may-be along the way... :S Thanks again for your huge help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval`. Check out the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
var requestCount = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    // Every 60 seconds, reset the count
    requestCount = 0;
}, 60000);

// There needs to be an additional check before calling rp,
// that checks for requestCount > 90, and returns before starting the request.

rp({
    url: uri,
    json: true,
})
.then((data) => {
    requestCount++;
    return data;
});
```

Comment: That doesnt make sense. It does not prevent requests from being made.

Comment: Yeah the request code does not explicitly stop requests from being made, but I'm assuming that it's going to be a part of something else? OP not clear. I was mainly trying to show using setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Probably just do 90 requests per minute. You could use a pseudorecursive promise utilizing function:

```
function multiRequest(urls, maxPerMinute){
 return new Promise(function(cb){
   var result = [];
   //iterate recursively
   (function next(i){
     //if finished resolve promise
     if(i>=urls.length) return cb(result);
      //get all requests
      var requests = Promise.all(urls.slice(i,i+maxPerMinute).map(request));

      //if the requests are done, add them to result
      requests.then(data=>result.push(...data));        

      //if the requests + one minute done, conginue with next
      Promise.all([
        requests,
        new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,1000*60))    
      ] ).then(_=>next(i+maxPerMinute))
 })(0);
 });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 multiRequests(["google.com","stackoverflow.com"],90)
  .then(([google,so])=>...);
```

Comment: Hey Jonas! Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand it fully though... Sorry, this is definitely because of my lack of knowledge. Matt's solution seems to work for me up to the `Promise.all` module in my code... If you had more insight on your solution it will be more than welcome! I'm going to read more about promise.all ...

Comment: @ardzii what do these requests return? Do you need to collect the data?

Comment: that's actually exactly what I'm working on: I'm getting different information from 3 different servers. Afterwards the objective is to crunch some of the information + store it in a db.

Comment: Hey Jonas! Thanks a lot for the follow-up! I don't want to be anymore of a bother but if I understand correctly, I'm a little concerned about the timeout: Wouldn't this mean that it's gonna wait 60 seconds before the next `Promise.all` ?
Also, I'm not sure I understand fully what's being returned here : `if(i>=urls.length) return cb(result);` Isn't it for the end of the iteration loop? If so, what's the `cb` suppose to be/to do? Many thanks as usual!

Comment: @ardzii yes youre right. The cb is there to resolve the promise at the end of the iteration. And yes, there will he just *maxPerMinute* requests per minute, i thought thats what you wanted.

Comment: Hey! Thanks again man for the follow-up. Regarding the 1 minutes that's exactly what I'm looking for :P However in that case, I'm not sure it will work with my code. See I have a module for each action and each `Promise.all` makes about 10 requests so just to be sure: I'll still be able to make various `Promise.all` within one minute (about 9 in that case)?
If you want a sneek peek at my code you can go there: https://github.com/Ardzii/mongoNode

Comment: @ardzii yes, shure. You can call multiRequest as often as you want, every limit just limits to the passed requests.