# How to do recursive requests to an API with promise in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I need to read data from API that only gives 100 results per query and a timestamp from where to get the next 100.

I've managed to do multiple requests one after another with the code below, but for some reason it never returns to the original promise. It gets stuck on the "No more orders to fetch".

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

  const getOrders = (from) => {
    return request(mcfApiUrl + "changes?created_after_ts="+from+"&key="+mcfKey)
    .then(xml => convert.xmlDataToJSON(xml,{explicitArray:false,mergeAttrs:true}))
    .then(orders => checkForMore(orders));
  }

  const checkForMore = (orders) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (orders['Orders']['orders'] == 100){
        getOrders(orders['Orders']['time_to']);
        console.log("Fetched "+ orders['Orders']['orders']+" orders");
        console.log("More orders available from: "+moment(orders['Orders']['time_to']*1000).format());
      }
      else {
        console.log("Fetched "+ orders['Orders']['orders']+" orders");
        console.log("No more orders to fetch");
        resolve(orders);
      }
    });
  };

  var fromdate = 1483999200;

  getOrders(fromdate)
  .then(output => res.send("Done")) // It never gets here
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: looking for an infinite loop of ajax requests?

Comment: I'd recommend using an event emitter or an observable instead

Comment: @Hitmands: The if statement should make it non-infinite.

Comment: @MinusFour: I'm open to other solutions as well. I just thought my solution would be quite simple (if it worked...)

Comment: May have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536280/node-js-best-way-to-handle-max-requests-per-minute-to-a-server/45536461#45536461

Comment: You aren't resolving in the `if()` ... try `resolve( getOrders(orders['Orders']['time_to']))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not resolving the `checkForMore` promise for all options.

```
const checkForMore = (orders) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (orders['Orders']['orders'] == 100){
        getOrders(orders['Orders']['time_to']); // <-- not resolved
      }
      else {
        resolve(orders);
      }
    });
  };
```

Just wrapping the call to `getOrders` with `resolve` will fix that.

```
resolve(getOrders(orders['Orders']['time_to']))
```

However, you don't really need to create a new promise:

```
const checkForMore = (orders) => 
  orders['Orders']['orders'] == 100
    ? getOrders(orders['Orders']['time_to'])
    : Promise.resolve(orders);
```

In fact, your entire function can be shrunk into a few lines:

```
const getOrders = (from) => 
  request(mcfApiUrl + "changes?created_after_ts="+from+"&key="+mcfKey)
    .then(xml => convert.xmlDataToJSON(xml,{explicitArray:false,mergeAttrs:true}))
    .then(orders => 
      orders.Orders.orders == 100
        ? getOrders(orders.Orders.time_to)
        : Promise.resolve(orders)
    );
```

Now, if you want to accumulate all the orders, you need to maintain some state through the recursion levels.

You can do that either with a global state or an additional parameter:

```
const getOrders = (from, allOrders = []) => 
  //                     ^ accumulation container
  request(mcfApiUrl + "changes?created_after_ts="+from+"&key="+mcfKey)
    .then(xml => convert.xmlDataToJSON(xml,{explicitArray:false,mergeAttrs:true}))
    .then(orders => {
      allOrders.push(orders); // <-- accumulate
      return orders.Orders.orders == 100
        ? getOrders(orders.Orders.time_to, allOrders) // <-- pass through recursion
        : Promise.resolve(allOrders)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! The resolve(getOrders(orders['Orders']['time_to'])) was the missing piece! :)

Comment: @Jopi glad to help :)